# sed regex replace on solaris

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, solaris

I have a file dummy.txt containing this:

```
"my_server"\1\"n9j7gd8kl4"
"widget"\1\"vnhck67hn"
"other_server"\1\"tbone"
"blah"\1\"n9j7gd8kl4"
"server_new"\1\"g54"
"genserver"\1\"vf45s"
"prd+other_server"\1\"f"\"jh34t"
"test_blah"\1\"tbone"
```

I need to change it to this with a generic-like one-liner in Solaris (can anyone please help?):

```
"my_server"\1\"tbone"
"widget"\1\"vnhck67hn"
"other_server"\1\"tbone"
"blah"\1\"n9j7gd8kl4"
"server_new"\1\"tbone"
"genserver"\1\"tbone"
"prd+other_server"\1\"f"\"jh34t"
"test_blah"\1\"tbone"
```

ie. For every line that has the string 'server' within the first double quotes and the line is in the format "string1"\1\"string2" then change the value of string2 to 'tbone'

Comment: will need to ignore lines that have \ or " within the string1 or string2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/^\("[^"]*server[^"]*"\\1\\\)".*"$/\1"tbone"/'
```

This allows 'server' to appear anywhere within the first string, not just at the end as in all the examples.  If you only want it at the end, omit the second `[^"]*`.

Oh, and to deal with the 'no double quotes or backslashes' requirement:

```
sed 's/^\("[^\\"]*server[^\\"]*"\\1\\\)"[^\\"]*"$/\1"tbone"/'
```

The difference is the backslashes in the negated character classes.

Comment: how would you use this to modify part of the file in place? ie modify all lines from: $(cat dummy.txt | grep -v ne | tail -4). I know cat dummy.txt | grep -v ne | tail -4 |sed -i 's/^\("[^\\"]*server[^\\"]*"\\1\\\)"[^\\"]*"$/\1"tbone"/' won't work

Comment: On Solaris, I'd use `grep -v ne dummy.txt | ... | sed ... >dummy.new; mv dummy.new dummy.txt`, or something equivalent.  In a script, I'd use traps and a unique intermediate file name to ensure that there aren't concurrency problems.  If the file might be multiply linked or a symlink, then the final `mv` needs to become `cp` plus `rm`, etc.  But basically, you filter the input to a file and then copy/move the file to the input.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean the new file will not contain any lines that didn't meet the grep/tail?

Comment: I've lost track of what you're asking.  You need to ask a new question, with sample inputs and outputs.  You can limit the range of lines that `sed` operates on, by number or by pattern (or a combination).

Answer (score 1):

```
cat dummy.txt | perl -pe 's{ ^ (" [^"\\]* server [^"\\]* " \\1 \\") [^"\\]+ " $}{${1}tbone"}xms;'
```

The Perl version is slightly more readable.

Comment: how would you use this to modify part of the file in place? ie modify all lines from: $(cat dummy.txt | grep -v ne | tail -4). I know cat dummy.txt | grep -v ne | tail -4 |sed -i 's/^\("[^\\"]*server[^\\"]*"\\1\\\)"[^\\"]*"$/\1"tbone"/' won't work